# JSON and HTML troubles

Tags: ajax

i'm currently having some troubles with displaying the information from a JSON file to html. I'm currently using AJAX to get the data from the JSON file. 
The main problem that i'm facing is with displaying all the data into one div.

```
    function Test(){
  request.open('GET','/json/anime.json');
  request.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if((request.readyState===4) && (request.status===200)) {
      var json = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
      for(var title in json.Title ) {
        for(var ep in json.Episode) {
          for(var img in json.Image) {
            for(var link in json.Link) {
              _title = json.Image[title];
              episode = json.Image[ep];
              image = json.Image[img];
              _link = json.Image[link];
              var div = document.createElement('div');
              div.className = 'card card-inverse';
              div.innerHTML = `<a href="${_link}"><img class="card-img img-fluid img-responsive" src="${image}" data-toggle="modal"></a>`;
              document.getElementById('anime').appendChild(div);
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  request.send();
}
```

The JSON file looks like this...

```
{
    Episode: [
        ...    
    ],
    Image: [
        ...
    ],
    Link: [
        ...
    ],
    Title: [
        ...
    ]
}
```

The way above is working if i'm only looping over one of the four arrays, however crashes chrome when trying to do the above task.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Wouldn't it better if you could make the json file like this: 
`{
   0: {episode: "episode1", image: "image_of_episode_1.png", link: "http://link1.com", title: "title of ep.1"}
   1: {episode: "episode2", image: "image_of_episode_2.png", link: "http://link2.com", title: "title of ep.2"}`

That way you could iterate through episodes with one single loop. I rember i used a php function that reorder the array like so, but i don't even know what server language are you using to create that json array, so i don't know if it would be usefull or not

Comment: Also i think the current loop is wrong, because you're doing like a cartesian product of all the elements of an anime. If you cannot reorder the json array like i said in the previous comment, you should get the length of an inner array (for example "titles") and then loop and integer value e get all the elements with that index

Comment: Have you tried using `map` instead of a lot of for loops ? You can easily transform that structure into an array and then map over it. You can do this: `Object.keys(jsonObject).map()` and then work from there.

Comment: Thanks for the quick comments guys, got it working. Re-worked how i was  constructing the loop. Thanks for that @MattiaNocerino.

Comment: @Cheese you're welcome. If you can, add your own answer and accept it, so other people will see which solution you adopted and make it easier for them!

Answer (score 1):

I decided to take a different approach moving away from ajax a little and moving more towards jquery. Below is what has so far worked out for me. Thanks to the people who commented above, really helped me think of ways to tackling it.

```
function DisplayCards() {
  var i = 0;
  $.getJSON('/json/anime.json', function(data) {
      $.each(data, function(index) {
        for(key in data[index]){
          e = data.Image.length;
          console.log(e);
          if(i < e)
          {
            image = data.Image[key];
            link = data.Link[key];

            console.log(i += 1);
            var div = document.createElement('div');
            div.className = 'card card-inverse';
            div.innerHTML = `<a href="${link}"><img class="card-img img-fluid img-responsive" src="${image}" data-toggle="modal"></a>`;
            var p = document.createElement('p');
            p.innerHTML = 'id="wrapper" class="text"';
            document.getElementById('anime').appendChild(div);
          }
        }
        console.log(data);


      });
  });
}
```